# What is the better way to cut a string including 2-byte character in Java

Tags: java, split, substring, message, cjk

I'm writing a method that creates a fixed-length message for the interface between the other two systems.

The message must be transmitted by the agreed length (byte) for each item, but if it is longer than the agreed length, the message should be truncated by the length of the item.

The message contains 2-byte characters, so if it is truncated in the middle of a character, it will be truncated to a broken state.

In order to calculate the correct byte, it will search for the length to be cut from the beginning. If the message is very long, the performance should be bad.

I can't find a better way, so I ask for help here. I'm sorry that the code is complicated and redundant. The entire project is available [here](https://github.com/thecodinglog/stringHelper).

```
package thecodinglog.string;

public class StringHelper {

public static String substrb2(String str, Number beginByte) {
    return substrb2(str, beginByte, null, null, null);
}

public static String substrb2(String str, Number beginByte, Number byteLength) {
    return substrb2(str, beginByte, byteLength, null, null);
}

/**
 * Returns the substring of the String.
 * It returns a string as specified length and byte position.
 * You can pad characters left or right when there is a specified length.
 * It distinguishes between 1 byte character and 2 byte character and returns it exactly as specified byte length.
 * If the start position or the specified length causes a 2-byte character to be truncated in the middle,
 * it will be converted to Space.
 * You can specify either left or right padding.
 *
 * If beginByte is 0, it is changed to 1 and processed.
 * If beginByte is less than 0, the string is searched for from right to left.
 * If beginByte or byteLength is a real number, the decimal point is discarded.
 * If you do not specify a length, returns everything from the starting position to the right-end string.
 *
 * Examples:
 * <blockquote><pre>
 *     StringHelper.substrb2("a好호b", 1, 10, null, "|") returns "a好호b||||"
 *     StringHelper.substrb2("ab한글", 4, 2) returns "  "
 *     StringHelper.substrb2("한a글", -3, 2) returns "a "
 *     StringHelper.substrb2("abcde한글이han gul다ykd", 7) returns " 글이han gul다ykd"
 * </pre></blockquote>
 *
 * @param str a string to substring
 * @param beginByte the beginning byte
 * @param byteLength length of bytes
 * @param leftPadding a character for padding. It must be 1 byte character.
 * @param rightPadding a character for padding. It must be 1 byte character.
 * @return a substring
 */
public static String substrb2(String str, Number beginByte, Number byteLength, String leftPadding, String rightPadding) {
    if (str == null || str.equals("")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The source string can not be an empty string or null.");
    }

    if (leftPadding != null && rightPadding != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Left padding, right padding Either of two must be null.");
    }

    if (leftPadding != null) {
        if (leftPadding.length() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The length of the padding string must be one.");
        }
        if (getByteLengthOfChar(leftPadding.charAt(0)) != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The padding string must be 1 Byte character.");
        }
    }

    if (rightPadding != null) {
        if (rightPadding.length() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The length of the padding string must be one.");
        }
        if (getByteLengthOfChar(rightPadding.charAt(0)) != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The padding string must be 1 Byte character.");
        }
    }

    int beginPosition = beginByte.intValue();
    if (beginPosition == 0) beginPosition = 1;

    int length;
    if (byteLength != null) {
        length = byteLength.intValue();
        if (length < 0) {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        length = -1;
    }

    if (length == 0)
        return null;

    boolean beginHalf = false;
    int accByte = 0;
    int startIndex = -1;

    if (beginPosition >= 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (beginPosition - 1 == accByte) {
                startIndex = i;
                accByte = accByte + getByteLengthOfChar(str.charAt(i));
                break;
            } else if (beginPosition == accByte) {
                beginHalf = true;
                startIndex = i;
                accByte = accByte + getByteLengthOfChar(str.charAt(i));
                break;
            } else if (accByte + 2 == beginPosition && i == str.length() - 1) {
                beginHalf = true;
                accByte = accByte + getByteLengthOfChar(str.charAt(i));
                break;
            }
            accByte = accByte + getByteLengthOfChar(str.charAt(i));
        }
    } else {
        beginPosition = beginPosition * -1;
        if(length > beginPosition){
            length = beginPosition;
        }

        for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            accByte = accByte + getByteLengthOfChar(str.charAt(i));

            if (i == str.length() - 1) {
                if (getByteLengthOfChar(str.charAt(i)) == 1) {
                    if (beginPosition == accByte) {
                        startIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (beginPosition == accByte) {
                        if (length > 1) {
                            startIndex = i;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            beginHalf = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }else if(beginPosition == accByte - 1){
                        if(length == 1){
                            beginHalf = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (getByteLengthOfChar(str.charAt(i)) == 1) {
                    if (beginPosition == accByte) {
                        startIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (beginPosition == accByte) {
                        if (length > 1) {
                            startIndex = i;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            beginHalf = true;
                            break;
                        }

                    } else if(beginPosition == accByte - 1) {
                        if(length > 1){
                            startIndex = i + 1;
                        }
                        beginHalf = true;
                        break;

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }


    if (accByte < beginPosition) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The start position is larger than the length of the original string.");
    }


    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    int accSubstrLength = 0;

    if (beginHalf) {
        stringBuilder.append(" ");
        accSubstrLength++;
    }


    if (byteLength == null) {
        stringBuilder.append(str.substring(startIndex));
        return new String(stringBuilder);
    }


    for (int i = startIndex; i < str.length() && startIndex >= 0; i++) {
        accSubstrLength = accSubstrLength + getByteLengthOfChar(str.charAt(i));
        if (accSubstrLength == length) {
            stringBuilder.append(str.charAt(i));
            break;
        } else if (accSubstrLength - 1 == length) {
                stringBuilder.append(" ");
            break;
        } else if (accSubstrLength - 1 > length) {

            break;
        }
        stringBuilder.append(str.charAt(i));
    }

    if (leftPadding != null) {
        int diffLength = byteLength.intValue() - accSubstrLength;
        StringBuilder padding = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < diffLength; i++) {
            padding.append(leftPadding);
        }
        stringBuilder.insert(0, padding);
    }

    if (rightPadding != null) {
        int diffLength = byteLength.intValue() - accSubstrLength;
        StringBuilder padding = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < diffLength; i++) {
            padding.append(rightPadding);
        }
        stringBuilder.append(padding);
    }


    return new String(stringBuilder);
}

private static int getByteLengthOfChar(char c) {
    if ((int) c < 128) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}
}
```

---

New tried code is

```
String testData = "한글이가득";

Charset charset = Charset.forName("EUC-KR");
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = charset.encode(testData);

byte[] newone = Arrays.copyOfRange(byteBuffer.array(), 1, 5);

CharsetDecoder charsetDecoder = charset.newDecoder()
        .replaceWith(" ")
        .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
        .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);

CharBuffer charBuffer = charsetDecoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(newone));

System.out.println(charBuffer.toString());
```

I expected " 글 " but "畸邦".
I think the start index must be correct position to decode but I don't think it's possible to make the method know what I want.

---

Add example fails

```
index| 0 1    2 3    4 5    6 7    8 9 
Char |   한  |   글  |   이 |   가  |  득   
---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ----  
hex  | c7d1 | b1db | c0cc | b0a1 | b5e6   
---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ----
```

Suppose that the starting index is 1 and length is 4 bytes, sub-hex-code will be like this

```
index| 0 1    2 3    4 5    6 7    8 9 
Char |   한  |   글  |   이 |   가  |  득   
---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ----  
hex  | c7d1 | b1db | c0cc | b0a1 | b5e6   
---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ----
sub  |   d1 | b1db | c0
```

When the decoder decodes *d1b1dbc0*, it treats *d1b1* as one character and treat *dbc0* as one character. This may vary depending on the character set, but in this case it changes like that. Unless the decoder knows the byte set of the original character, the decoder will decode it with the wrong character because the byte does not know the starting point.

I think the key to this method is how to get the decoder to know the starting position (in bytes) of the original character.

Comment: you're aware that char is two bytes in java?

Comment: This is a lot of code to ask people to go through... Please see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Can your whole question be rephrased as "find the longest truncation of a string for which the byte representation is under a given length ?" If so, I'd user a `CharsetEncoder`, append to it `char` by `char`, and wait untill the result overflows (or better, see the `encodeLoop` method)

Comment: Why would you transfer chars?  Decompose to bytes, transfer the bytes and at the other end compose the chars again from the bytes.

Comment: I don't think that char is two bytes or not is important @Rodney

Comment: yes. to transfer biz info to another system, I need to make it. @toongeorges

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to convert the whole String to byte[] and cut the array. Then try to convert the array piece back to String. If the conversion fails skip last byte of the piece array.

Comment: I'v tried already but the middle position of 2-byte character is problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a NIO method for that.

Using [`CharsetEncoder#encode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode(java.nio.CharBuffer,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20boolean)), one can encode a String (or rather a `CharBuffer`, but the conversion is trivial) to a byte array (actually a `ByteBuffer`), in a way that all possible characters from the input will be converted, up to the point where the input is fully processed, but never overflowing the output.

> CoderResult.OVERFLOW indicates that there is insufficient space in the output buffer to encode any more characters. This method should be invoked again with an output buffer that has more remaining bytes. This is typically done by draining any encoded bytes from the output buffer.

---

Follwing your edit, here is an example (althoug I'm still not sure what you want to accomplish, this is my best guess), with your String `한글이가득` using the encoding EUC-KR.

First, let's see what the byte array representation is for each char

```
Char |   한 |   글  |   이 |  가   |  득 
---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ----
hex  | c7d1 | b1db | c0cc | b0a1 | b5e6
```

So this whole string needs 10 bytes to be written

Now, say we have a message length of 9 bytes. This will allow us to send `한글이가` (8 bytes), which is `0xc7d12b1dbc0ccb0a1` but as there is not enough room to send `득` (it would require 2 more bytes for `0xb5e6`, and we have only one left), the rest of the buffer should be blank.

Indeed :

```
String testData = "한글이가득";
CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
// We create a 9 bytes buffer
ByteBuffer limitedSizeOutput = ByteBuffer.allocate(9);
// We encode
CoderResult coderResult = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(testData.toCharArray()), limitedSizeOutput, true);
// The encoder tells us that it could not fit the whole chars in 9 bytes
System.out.println(coderResult); // prints OVERFLOW
// We can check that it encoded 8 bytes out of the 10 that compose the original string data
limitedSizeOutput.flip();
System.out.println(limitedSizeOutput.limit()); // prints 8
// We can see that these are in effect 한글이가 by reading the uffer
System.out.println(charset.newDecoder().decode(limitedSizeOutput).toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'v tried to use NIO methods but I wasn't able to get result what I want. the code above.

Comment: @JeongjinKim i've edited to clarify. If this does not work for you, then I probably misunderstood your intent. Could you please clarify too ?

Comment: In fact there is no problem when I cut from beginning of string(index 0). but if I want cut from in the middle of string there is a complicated problem. I will edit my Q more detail.

Comment: I see. Do not think of it in terms of "I need to cut the 18 first bytes", because it won't work. Think of it in terms of "I need to cut the first 2 messages of 9 bytes each" (which actually do not correspond to 18 bytes of usefull message, but 16 in the example above). The you have a usable way : use a loop of the code above to create the messages, discard the first two, emit the third.